# Vertical alignment of tikzpicture within tabular / change to current bounding box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

See inset mwe.  Note that `current bounding box.top` previously worked, no longer seems to.  `current bounding box.north` illustrates the general goal of this table but suffers from a vertical alignment issue of the symbol with the corresponding description text.  Middle vertical alignment of the description text with the symbol may be most desired.  I am, however, open to alternative suggestions.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{filecontents}%
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%
\newcommand\calltikzsymbol[4]{%
%\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,y=\yunit, x=\xunit,xscale=#2,yscale=#3, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,%
baseline=(current bounding box.north)]% **** works, but vertical alignment is not desireable
%baseline=(current bounding box.top)]% **** this worked previously, doesn't seem to now
\input{#4}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%


% SYMBOL

\begin{filecontents}{needle_valve.tex}
\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] (392.8074,233.6943) -- 
 (392.8074,209.7008);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] (363.0429,263.1322) 
 -- (390.7731,247.1222);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] 
 (388.3074,233.6943) -- (392.8074,258.2010);\path[draw=black,line 
 width=0.480pt] (363.0429,228.7631) -- 
 (390.2906,244.4946);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] (397.3088,233.6943) 
 -- (392.8074,258.2010);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] 
 (422.5720,263.1322) -- (394.8424,247.1222);\path[draw=black,line 
 width=0.480pt] (422.5720,228.7631) -- 
 (395.3251,244.4941);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] (392.8074,233.6943) 
 -- (388.3074,233.6943);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] 
 (392.8074,233.6943) -- (388.3074,233.6943);\path[draw=black,line 
 width=0.480pt] (392.8074,233.6943) -- 
 (397.3088,233.6943);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] (397.3088,233.6943) 
 -- (392.8074,233.6943);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] 
 (363.0429,245.9476) -- (337.1305,245.9476);\path[draw=black,line 
 width=0.480pt] (392.8074,209.7008) -- 
 (405.7584,209.7008);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] (363.0429,228.7631) 
 -- (363.0429,263.1322);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] 
 (422.5720,228.7631) -- (422.5720,263.1322);\path[draw=black,line 
 width=0.480pt] (422.5720,245.9476) -- 
 (448.4843,245.9476);\path[draw=black,line width=0.480pt] (379.8564,209.7008) 
 -- (392.8074,209.7008);\path[fill=black] (397.3088,233.6943) -- 
 (392.8074,233.6943) -- (388.3074,233.6943) -- (392.8074,258.2010) -- 
 (397.3088,233.6943) -- cycle;`
\end{filecontents}


% PARAMETERS


% define default symbol scale
\def\defaultsymbolscale{1.2}

% default horizontal orientation (inverse achieves horizontal flip)
\def\defaultxscale{-1}

% default vertical orientation (inverse achieves vertical flip)
\def\defaultyscale{-1}

% set x grid unit
\newlength\xunit{}
\setlength\xunit{0.8pt}

% set y grid unit
\newlength\yunit{}
\setlength\yunit{0.8pt}

% define width for the table
\newlength\descriptioncolumnwidth{}
\setlength\descriptioncolumnwidth{5.5cm}

% vertical spacing
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{3.1mm}


% CONTENT

\begin{document}%

%
\begin{tabular}{cp{\descriptioncolumnwidth}}%
\toprule%
Symbol & Description \\%
\midrule \addlinespace%
\calltikzsymbol{\defaultsymbolscale}{\defaultxscale}{\defaultyscale}{needle_valve.tex} &  Needle valve\\ \addlinespace%
\calltikzsymbol{\defaultsymbolscale}{\defaultxscale}{\defaultyscale}{needle_valve.tex} &  Same sh\#t, different line.  This line happens to have a longer description which spans multiple lines.  It is worth considering this case; top alignment may actually look better in this case.  Open to suggestions.\\ \addlinespace%
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

Output is also inset:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You say that the vertical alignment you're getting is "not desired" but you haven't said very clearly what you actually want. Do you want the head of the black arrow to touch the heads to the two adjacent white triangles? Secondly we can't compile your code without seeing `needle_valve.tex` and this is almost certainly relevant to your question, so it would be good if you could include this. I have to say that including code like this is a little unusual. Is there a good reason for doing this? When I want to be able to easily reuse commands I put them into a style file.

Comment: Meta issue with blockquote button.  I edited the question just now.

Comment: I have included the definition of the `\calltikzsymbol` in this mwe solely for the purpose of compactness.  It usually resides in an `.sty`.

Comment: Great, but `\calltikzsymbol` itself loads the file `needle_valve.tex`, which you have not included.

Comment: Is an instance of the `filecontents` environment not visible?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that...

Answer (score 1):

`baseline=(current bounding box.center)` seems to work well enough

Comment: Could you explain your answer well adding a complete code, please, with an image? Thank you very much.